# Sending ATA security unlock 0xF2 in Windows

Tags: windows, security, device, ioctl, ata

I am trying to apply the recommendations from:
[Sending ATA commands directly to device in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070987/sending-ata-commands-directly-to-device-in-windows)
My goal is to send ATA 0xF2 (security unlock-0xF2) to the just connected via USB (usb to SATA) SSD, which was locked previously with known password. The same issue in Linux was extensively tested with hdparm utility and works fine.

I tried this code on Win-7,8,10 - all versions return error code 50 (the request is not supported). For the test purpose I issued 0xEC command - worked fine.

How do I push this 0xF2 ATA command to the SSD?
Any hints/thoughts/help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, don't use the ATA security commands through a USB adapter. They are known to malfunction and can result in a locked disk that won't accept the original password.

There is no built in command in Windows to do this. There is a tool called Victoria which can send ATA commands.

http://malthus.mooo.com/viewtopic.php?t=1072