# Sending ATA command "Read native max address (0x27 , 0xF8) not reponding over SAS controller using SAT(SCSI ATA translate)

Tags: translation, scsi, ata

i want to find out native max address of an HDD over SAS interface.
i am using SAT ( scsi ata translation) with SCSI_PASS_THROUGH.

but unable to find out any buffer or valid senseinfo of SCSI_PASS_THROUGH
with IOCTL_SCSI_PASS_THROUGH from drive.
cdb value of SCSI_PASS_THROUGH =

```
sptwb.Spt.CdbLength = 12;
        sptwb.Spt.Cdb[0] = 0xA1;//ATA PASS THROUGH(12) OPERATION CODE(A1h)
        sptwb.Spt.Cdb[1] = (4 << 1) | 0; 
        sptwb.Spt.Cdb[2] = (1 << 3) | (1 << 2) | 2;
        sptwb.Spt.Cdb[3] = 0xe0;
        sptwb.Spt.Cdb[4] = 0x00;
        sptwb.Spt.Cdb[5] = 0x00;
        sptwb.Spt.Cdb[6] = 0x00;
        sptwb.Spt.Cdb[7] = 0x00;
        sptwb.Spt.Cdb[8] = (UCHAR)0x40;//(UCHAR)head;
        sptwb.Spt.Cdb[9] = 0x27;//COMMAND
```

But not return any buffer.
Please provide exact cdb parameters to read native max address on SAS machine.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have all relevant SCSI Specs in front of me.  Therefore, I'm assuming you're building the SATL **(SCSI ATA Translation Layer)** CDB correctly.  The first thing to check for is whether the ioctl completed.  That is, check the return code of `DeviceIoControl()` for `True` or `False` and then check `GetLastError()` to determine what went wrong (if applicable).  If the ioctl was fine, check the [SCSI_PASS_THROUGH_DIRECT structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff565346%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) member `.ScsiStatus`.  If this is 0, then the command completed just fine.  If the status was 0, this may well be the reason for no valid sense info.

I was actually researching this very command when I stumbled onto this thread.  The most recent ATA Command Spec, ACS-3 (dated October 28, 2013) shows that the **Read Native Max Address** and **Read Native Max Address Ext** commands are now obsolete.  I found their definition in ACS-2.  The [most recent draft](http://www.t13.org/Documents/UploadedDocuments/docs2009/d2015r2-ATAATAPI_Command_Set_-_2_ACS-2.pdf), dated August 3, 2009, shows that the output of this command won't be a buffer.  Rather, the output will be in the LBA field of the returned **Device-To-Host FIS**.

---

**Addendum**
The verbiage of the original post lead me to believe this was being done in Windows.  I should have included that the process will be the same for Linux, if that is what you're using.  However, don't use `GetLastError()` to determine what went wrong.  In Linux, the return code from `ioctl()` will be the code you need.

If in Linux, you're most likely using the **sg** driver and [the sg_io_hdr_t structure](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/SCSI-Generic-HOWTO/sg_io_hdr_t.html).  This structure also has a `.status` member which contains the SCSI Status code.  Whether in Linux or Windows, you should always check this code because assuming the command succeeded because the ioctl did is a fallacy.  There are other pass through drivers available in Linux, e.g. the LSI MPT interface.  The process is still the same if this is what you're using.

Answer (score 0):

The command you're trying to implement, 0xF8 (Read Native Max Address) is not a SCSI command, it's an ATA command.

CDB code 0xA1 does indeed work with with the IOCTL_SCSI_PASS_THROUGH API to get SCSI/ATAPI commands to a device. But that's not what you want.

Try [IOCTL_ATA_PASSTHROUGH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559309(v=vs.85).aspx) instead.

Example and discussion here:
[Sending ATA commands directly to device in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5070987/sending-ata-commands-directly-to-device-in-windows)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want:
This works under cygwin or native linux having "sg3_utils" installed.

```
#!/bin/bash
dev=$1
sz=$(sg_raw 2>/dev/null -r 40 $dev 9e 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0c 00 00 -b|xxd -p)
nb=$((0x${sz:0:16}+1))
bs=$((0x${sz:16:8}))
pbs=$((bs*2**0x${sz:24:4}))
echo Real number of blocks: $nb
echo Real HDD Size: $((nb*bs))
echo Logical Block Size: $bs
echo Physical Block Size: $pbs
p=$((0x$(sg_raw 2>/dev/null $dev -r 512 85 08 0e 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ec 00 -o -|xxd -c 0 -ps|while read -N1 a;do read -N1 b;echo -n $b$a;done|cut -c 401-416|rev)))
echo User Addressable blocks: $p
echo User Addressable size: $(($p*bs))
```

```
./gethdsize.sh PD2 (device obtained with sg_scan)
```

output:

```
Real number of blocks: 27344764928
Real HDD Size: 14000519643136
Logical Block Size: 512
Physical Block Size: 4096
User Addressable blocks: 27344750581
User Addressable size: 14000512297472
```

after resetting drive to max lba:

```
Real number of blocks: 27344764928
Real HDD Size: 14000519643136
Logical Block Size: 512
Physical Block Size: 4096
User Addressable blocks: 27344764928
User Addressable size: 14000519643136
```